# Is it possible to complie non-ansi C code on Ubuntu 22.04.4?

Tags: compiler

I have an old piece of non-ANSI C code I wrote years ago that complied well on System 5 Unix running on a AT&T 3B2 micro computer. After I left engineering to go into medicine my C coding experience has rusted but not my love for Unix and now Linux. If you tell me to just convert the old code to ANSI C then so be it.

Comment: Try a compile and see what errors you get.  Then check the man page for gcc and see if there are options to set to handle the situation.  Or update the problem code.

Comment: It's going to depend on which specific non-ANSI features / behaviors your code relies on I think - for the GCC compiler, a good starting point might be [Incompatibilities of GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.4.0/gcc/Incompatibilities.html). If your code relies on third-party libraries, then their availability and API stability may be a bigger issue than simple dialect differences.

Comment: Try it, read the errors, debug/update. Repeat.